# sweetalert2 not waiting for confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2

I am having some trouble getting sweetalert2 working on one of the pages of my site. I have the following code:

```
<?php
    deletepost.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "&album=" . $row["photoalbum"];
?>
<script>
    function confirmdelete(){
        swal({
            title: 'Delete Post',
            text: 'Are you sure you want to delete this post? You cannot undo this.',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Delete Ride',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancel'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                window.location = '<?php echo $url; ?>';                }
        })
    }
</script>
<a href="deletepost.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>&album=<?php echo $row["photoalbum"]; ?>" onclick="confirmdelete()"> <b>Delete Post</b></a><br><br>
```

If I click the Delete Link post, it pops up the confirmation box for a second, but then the box closes and it goes to the next page without waiting for input from the user.

I tried doing the following, but it doesn't always work:

```
<a href="#" onclick="confirmdelete()"> <b>Delete Post</b></a><br><br>
```

I am loading a separate javascript file for photo albums that for some reason blocks this. The file is called prototype.js and is part of the Lightbox photo album plug in. I removed this file and the a href="#" worked fine, but the photo album didn't display correctly. I can paste the code from prototype.js if needed.

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Use button with type 'button' instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that didn't work. What I believe is the problem is that the prototype.js is blocking the onclick() for some reason.

Comment: What behavior do you have when you use button? Also look at your browser console to see if there are any error message.